# Shiny output doesn't work when followed by another command

Tags: r, shiny

Why does my shiny output command print when both the Sys.sleep and the source commands are commented but does not print when either are uncommented?

```
ui <- fluidPage(
    actionButton("test", "Test"),
    
    textOutput("textout1")
   
  )

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  
  observeEvent(input$test, {
    
    output$textout1 <- renderText({"Print this"})
    #Sys.sleep(1000)
    #source("foo.R")
    
  })
  

}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Works fine for me. But Sys.sleep will add a pause, i.e. the text will be rendered only after 1000 seconds.

Comment: I'd avoid nesting `renderXXX` functions in observers and use `bindEvent` on `renderText` instead.

Comment: Really?  It works for you?  That is strange.

Comment: I don't understand bindEvent() Is it a replacement for observeEvent()?